# Regarding production URL

Tags: apex

DID Production URL got changed? IF so please update the new one? I am giving correct uname and pwd but unable to login so some one please help me out. EVen I  created new pwd and tried still not working so please help me

Comment: Maybe you've mixed up your username with email address? They can be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The production URL is : https://login.salesforce.com.

The URL will be different if you are using a custom domain and will not be allowed if your administrator has [disabled logins](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_setting_login_policy.htm&language=en_US) from above URL. Please check with administrator of your organisation.

If you are a user and not administrator, please ask your administrator to reset your password or you can do it yourselves using FORGOT PASSWORD link.

If you are the only administrator and you are sure that your password and Username is correct, please try resetting your password or directly call salesforce support.

Changing your password will also change the security token and if the same account is used for API Integration, they may fail. [Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=resetting_and_expiring_passwords.htm&language=en)